# Getting the error "can't load fmt" - golangci-lint

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I installed golangci-lint using the link

```
# binary will be $(go env GOPATH)/bin/golangci-lint
curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.54.2
```

> golangci/golangci-lint info found version: 1.54.2 for
> v1.54.2/darwin/amd64 golangci/golangci-lint info installed
> /Users/prajeeshb/go/bin/golangci-lint

Now if i type the command **golangci-lint --version** i am getting the following error.

```
panic: load embedded ruleguard rules: rules/rules.go:13: can't load fmt

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/go-critic/go-critic/checkers.init.22()
    github.com/go-critic/go-critic@v0.6.3/checkers/embedded_rules.go:47 +0x4b4
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could be related to the go version. Try to update the version of [go-critic](https://github.com/go-critic/go-critic). See also [this](https://github.com/go-critic/go-critic/issues/1359) and [this](https://github.com/go-critic/go-critic/issues/1060) related issues